# Should I use @Transactional or @Rollback for DAO test classes?

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit, dao

I have a dao layer for my database. Now, I am writing some integration tests for it. I wonder if **@Transactional** or **@Rollback** should be used in a test class, as they both revert the changes to the database. Which one would be a **good practice and in what conditions**?

I tried using both of them and they both work in my case. I have a @Before annotated method in my class.

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = NONE)
@DataJpaTest
// @Transactional or @Rollback?
public class TestDao {

    @Autowired
    private ConcreteDao concreteDao;

    @Before
    public void cleanUp(){ . . . }

    @Test
    public void testSaveAllEntries(){ . . . }

    // and other tests
}
```

Comment: "Which one would be a good practice" testing a database in a unit test is already bad practice in and of itself. Relying on reverting state sounds even worse

Comment: See similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51277657/how-unit-test-insert-record-in-spring-no-delete-method/51277993?noredirect=1#comment89534370_51277993

Comment: Check the official Spring Framework reference documentation for [Enabling and Disabling Transactions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-tx-enabling-transactions). It is enough to use only `@Transactional`

Answer (score 0):

agree with @michael Don't make your tests @transactional at all (but your service layer)This means that all your service layer/persistence layer methods invoked through the tests would start their own transactions (you made them transactional, did you?) and flush the changes upon commit. So you are guaranteed to notice if something blows up on flush, and quite possible that  after a while, a database full of junk test data

Comment: So, should I remove @Transactional annotation from the class and run it as is? My dao methods are not transactional, I know that transaction should be created in service layer (for specific methods), am I right?

Comment: 'yes you should handle these things on service layer instead of your test. 

Also in official documentation it's mentioned.

By default, test transactions will be automatically rolled back after completion of the test; however, transactional commit and rollback behavior can be configured declaratively via the `@Commit` and `@Rollback annotations `

Answer (score 0):

Running tests with databases usually will be done with integration tests. To keep it simple you could setup a h2 with the dialect you need. Prepare the database structures and run the service calls you need. assert the expecting results and mark the test method as dirties context (as annotation), or resetup the database with each test, otherwise saved results of a test could have impact of another test. In this way you can also test the transaction handling of your services.

Adding transactional to your tests will change your behaviour of your business logic. keep those out of your tests.